# Determine the core-nilpotent decomposition for P.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let P be a projector different from the identity. Determine the core-nilpotent decomposition for P.

I know that I can use the formula $Q^{-1} P Q$ and got the result $N =0$, but I don't know how to find $C$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $P$ is a projector, $P$ is annihilated by $X^2-X=X(X-1)$, a polynomial with distinct roots. So $P$ is diagonalizable, its only eigenvalues are $0$ ($s$ times) and $1$ ($t$ times) with $s+t=n$. We then have $C=I_t$, $L=0_s$.

Comment: are you implying that $C$ is $I$?

Comment: @DianeVanderwaif corrected, thanks.